# SSRS Subscription to an email group (distribution list) is not working

Tags: email, reporting-services, subscription

In SSRS, a subscription for email IDs is working properl,y but for a group email ID it's showing following message:

> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>
> Group Team (groupTeam@company.com) Your message can't be delivered
>   because delivery to this address is restricted.
>
> Diagnostic information for administrators:
>
> Generating server: CR-EX2010-CAS01.domain.ad.company.com
>
> groupTeam@company.com #550 5.7.1 RESOLVER.RST.AuthRequired;
>   authentication required ##

Original message headers:

> Received: from MachineName (1X.6X.1XX.2XX) by 
>   CR-EX2010-CAS01.domain.ad.company.com (1X.6X.1XX.1XX) with Microsoft
>   SMTP Server  id 14.2.342.3; Tue, 18 Jun 2013 12:10:10 +0000
>   Thread-Topic: TestEmailGroup_Local was executed at 6/18/2013 5:40:06
>   PM Local Report thread-index: Ac5sHMVttkcWf0iySVqJzLN2XGgn7g==
>   Reply-To: From:  To: Group Team
>    CC: BCC: Subject: TestEmailGroup_Local was
>   executed at 6/18/2013 5:40:06 PM Local Report Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2013
>   17:40:08 +0530 Message-ID:
>   <1D23A36E5012444DB165265B4F21BEF7@domain.ad.cmpany.com> MIME-Version:
>   1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed;             boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0001_01CE6C4A.E079EE30"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows
>   2000 Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message Importance: normal
>   Priority: normal X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE
>   V6.1.7601.17609 Return-Path: myemailid@company.com

My rsreportserver.config as follows

```
        <Extension Name="Report Server Email" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.EmailDeliveryProvider.EmailProvider,ReportingServicesEmailDeliveryProvider">
            <MaxRetries>3</MaxRetries>
            <SecondsBeforeRetry>900</SecondsBeforeRetry>
            <Configuration>
                <RSEmailDPConfiguration>
                    <SMTPServer>outlook.company.com</SMTPServer>
                    <SMTPServerPort></SMTPServerPort>
                    <SMTPAccountName></SMTPAccountName>
                    <SMTPConnectionTimeout></SMTPConnectionTimeout>
                    <SMTPServerPickupDirectory></SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
                    <SMTPUseSSL></SMTPUseSSL>
                    <SendUsing>2</SendUsing>
                    <SMTPAuthenticate></SMTPAuthenticate>
                    <From>myemailid@compny.com</From>
                    <EmbeddedRenderFormats>
                        <RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension>
                    </EmbeddedRenderFormats>
                    <PrivilegedUserRenderFormats></PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
                    <ExcludedRenderFormats>
                        <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension>
                    </ExcludedRenderFormats>
                    <SendEmailToUserAlias>True</SendEmailToUserAlias>
                    <DefaultHostName></DefaultHostName>
                    <PermittedHosts></PermittedHosts>
                </RSEmailDPConfiguration>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
```

And In the **SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)** Log On As

Option **This Account** : **Network Service**
and Password blank

Comment: In case of SMTPAuthenticate to 0, you can not send mail to outside domain and to the distributed list, And in case of SMTPAuthenticate to 2, you have to contact to your SMTP admin and ask him for "Send As" permission on the sender email id.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx#bkmk_confiugre_remote_SMTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer after some search, In case of SMTPAuthenticate to 0, you can not send mail to outside domain and to the distributed list, And in case of SMTPAuthenticate to 2, you have to contact to your SMTP admin and ask him for "Send As" permission on the sender email id.

Refer the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx#bkmk_confiugre_remote_SMTP

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the following first:

> Your message can't be delivered because delivery to this address is
>   restricted.

And:

> authentication required

By default, when connecting to an SMTP server SSRS will connect through Anonymous access.

To set up Authentication you will need to update the [RSReportServer Configuration File E-mail Extension Configuration Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#bkmk_email_extension).

From Books Online [Configure a Report Server for E-Mail Delivery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx) you need to update the config file to allow authenticated access to the SMTP server:

> SMTPAuthenticate specifies how the report server connects to the
>   remote SMTP server. The default value is 0 (or no authentication). In
>   this case, the connection is made through Anonymous access. Depending
>   on your domain configuration, the report server and the SMTP server
>   may need to be members of the same domain.
>
> To send e-mail to restricted distribution lists (for example,
>   distribution lists that accept incoming messages only from
>   authenticated accounts), set SMTPAuthenticate to 2.

The second paragraph seems to apply directly to your situation.

So the first thing to do is make sure **SMTPAuthenticate** is set correctly in **RsReportServer.config**.

If you get further authentication errors after enabling this you'll need to look at the SSRS service user and check its permissions with your email support team.

**Edit after comment:**

Based on your config file, you haven't changed `SMTPAuthenticate` to `2` as per the docs. What I meant above is that there is a rule in the SMTP server causing `Your message can't be delivered because delivery to this address is restricted` - it's because you're sending the message without authentication.

You can either try setting the SSRS service user as a domain user who can authenticate to the SMTP server with the relevant config file change, or you can try and change the rule causing the error; either way this will need to involve the person(s) responsible for the SMTP server configutation, i.e. the email support team.

Comment: Hi Ian added configuration in original question, also SSRS service user and its permissions with email support team means exactly what I have to do there.

Comment: I've added more detail to try and clarify everything.

Comment: I got answer after some search, In case of SMTPAuthenticate to 0, you can not send mail to outside domain and to the distributed list, And in case of SMTPAuthenticate to 2, you have to contact to your SMTP admin and ask him for "Send As" permission on the sender email id.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx#bkmk_confiugre_remote_SMTP