# SSRS - Reports not arriving for email groups

Tags: email, reporting-services, smtp

We have an issue where a 3rd party supplier is generating business critical reports from their SSRS server to distribute into our business via email.  The reports arrive without issue when each recipients individual email address is supplied.  However we now need to widen the audience of these reports and so we have created some query based distribution groups, eg sales@company.com.

I can send an email to this group from my own external email (Gmail) and it arrives fine.  However the reports sent from our supplier do not arrive when using the group emails?  We do not even see them hit our inbound email.

I have found a link which seems to describe the issue:

[SSRS Subscription to an email group (distribution list) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229368/ssrs-subscription-to-an-email-group-distribution-list-is-not-working)

And another which details how to setup local SMTP for SSRS:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx#bkmk_confiugre_remote_SMTP

However I am concerned that our supplier is not going to make any configuration changes at their end.  A start would be to understand why SSRS will not send to group emails when it has no issue with individual emails?  Has anyone had any experience of this issue?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

This type of issue usually has nothing to do with SSRS. It is probably generating the email and sending it. Once that is passed to the mail server, it has to have permissions to use those distribution lists, domains, etc. So it comes down to configuration on the mail server. If you can't get them to fix it, you'd have to have it forwarded through an email account that you can control.